# Spring Batch: JPA Repositories into writers doesn't work after setting a custom BatchConfigurer

Tags: spring-batch

I'm using JPA Repositories (interfaces extending `CrudRepository`) in order to save entities into my `writers`.

Everything did work fine, when I've added a custom `Batchconfigurer` in order to add a `taskExecutor` for working with http requests:

```java
@Component
public class ConnectorBatchConfigurer extends DefaultBatchConfigurer {

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public JobLauncher createJobLauncher() throws Exception {
        SimpleJobLauncher jobLauncher = new SimpleJobLauncher();

        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(super.getJobRepository());
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();

        return jobLauncher;
    }
}
```

Suddenly, entities are not saved and any error message is reported.

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `DefaultBatchConfigurer` configures a `DataSourceTransactionManager`. Since you use JPA, you need to override `getTransactionManager` and return a `JpaTransactionManager`:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Override
public PlatformTransactionManager getTransactionManager() {
   JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
   jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
   jpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
   return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

Please refer to the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/reference/html/job.html#javaConfig) for more details.

Comment: I'm getting a `java.lang.IllegalStateException: No EntityManagerFactory set` when I'm trying to save my entities using jpa respotories... Any idea?

Comment: Yeah, I left the task of correctly creating a JPA tx manager to you. But I updated the answer accordingly.